# axios.get function in ComponentDidMount not setting state as expected

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, rendering, state

In my header component, I have conditional rendering set to display different links depending on if the user is logged in or not. The conditional rendering works fine EXCEPT the fact that it blinks one set of links before displaying the proper set of links.

It dawned on me this is because of the `axios.get` call I have that retrieves the user's status. The state variable is initially set to false. If the user is logged in, the get call will indicate that and the state variable will get set to true. The short delay makes it so the "not logged in" links are shown momentarily before the "is logged in" links get displayed.

I've tried quite a few recommended approaches in both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` - nothing seems to be working:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
        withCredentials: true
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.data.loggedIn) {
            this.setState({isLogged: true});
        } else {
            this.setState({isLogged: false});
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({isLogged: false});
    });
}
```

Next approach:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
        withCredentials: true
    });
    const logged = await res.data.loggedIn;

    if (logged) {
        this.setState({isLogged: true});
    } else {
        this.setState({isLogged: false});
    }
}
```

I've tried call back functions with the same results.

The conditional rendering is the typical:

```
{this.state.isLogged && <LoggedIn />}
```

I'm clearly failing to see something basic in how the async functions work - I'm just not sure what that is!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a method I’ve found useful. Add a loading variable to state:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
        withCredentials: true
    });
    const logged = await res.data.loggedIn;

    if (logged) {
        this.setState({isLogged: true, loading: false });
    } else {
        this.setState({isLogged: false, loading: false });
    }
}
```

Then, you can add:

```
{!this.state.loading && this.state.isLogged && ...}
```

You can always set loading to true in your component’s constructor, if you still see a flash, but I would try to keep loading in the same method as the process that’s actually loading.

Comment: This seemed like a perfect idea but it doesn't seem to work. Regardless of the value I set in the constructor for loading, it still blinks the links before displaying the links I want. I tried it in both versions of the conponentDidMount function. I appreciate the idea!

Comment: Forget the comment above - I did it wrong...your suggestion was great and seems to work exactly as I wanted. I don't see the blinking any more! Thanks SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

The best that you can do in this case is to show nothing or a spinner until the request has finished. It doesn't matter what you do (async/await, promise, callback) that request is going to take some time.

Comment: I wouldn't show nothing, just show a "Loading" message, or a small spinner gif or something. Just so the user knows that the app is doing something. Always do this for async stuff.

Comment: He’s talking about a flash of the wrong links. Wouldn’t a flash of a spinner be just as bad? Why not just wait to load the new links until the get request is done?

Comment: twils0 That's what I'd love to be able to do - your suggestion sounds ideal...don't show anything until the info is ready to be displayed. What's an approach that I could ensure the axios call is completed before attempting to render the links?