# Not able to listen for data changes from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have used firebase for API in my React app, where it listens for the user data. When users data is updated, I am not able to listen for data changes in my React component. How to implement this functionality.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://organic-kart-3f887.firebaseio.com/users.json')
            .then(users => {
                this.setState({
                    users.data
                })
            })
    }
```

I am getting the user data, when the component is mounted. I am not able to listen for changes in users data in my app.

Comment: `console.log` users and verify if the `users` variable is exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah I am getting the user data when the component is mounted. I have been posting data to the firebase, it's getting updated in the firebase. But i am not able to listen for those changes in the component.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920311/axios-get-function-in-componentdidmount-not-setting-state-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest you change the exact data will be changed instead of directly changing the high-level use object itself. Please try the below approach.

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://organic-kart-3f887.firebaseio.com/users.json')
            .then(users => {
                this.setState({
                    users: {
                    ...this.state.users,
                    data

                })
            })
    }
```